# Grid sorting with persistent master sort

Tags: sorting, user-interface, grid

I have a UI with a grid.  Each record in the grid is sorted by a "master" sort column, let's call it a page number.  Each record is a story in a magazine.  I want the user to be able to drag and drop a record to a new position in the grid and automatically update the page number field to reflect the updated position.  Easy enough, right?

Now imagine that I also want to have the grid sortable by any other column (story title, section, author name, etc.).  How does the drag and drop operation work now?

- Revert to page number sort during or after the drag and drop operation?  This could confuse the user (why did my sort just change?).  It would also result in arbitrary row positioning.  Would the story now be before the row that was after it when the user dropped it?  Or, would it be after the row that was before it?  Those rows may now be widely separated after the master order sort.
- Disable the drag and drop feature if the grid isn't currently sorted by the page number?  This would be easy, but the user might wonder why he can't drag and drop at certain times.  Knowing to first sort by page number may not be very intuitive.
- Let the user rearrange his rows, but not make any changes to the page number?
- Require the user to enter a "Arrange Stories" mode, in which the grid sort is temporarily switched to page number and drag and drop is enabled?  They would then exit the mode, and the previous sort would be reapplied.  The big difference between this and the second option is that it would be more explicit than simply clicking on a column header.

Any other ideas, or reasons why one of the above is the way to go?

**EDIT**

I'd like to point out that any of the above is technically possible, and easy to implement.  My question is design-related.  What is the most intuitive way to solve this problem, from the user's perspective?

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you drop it into the list sorted by another method?

Comment: What would the page number be set to?  The rows before and after the drop location could have any page number values.

Comment: That's up to you. If dropping it in means you want it put to the end of the magazine, then set the page number to be the next available page. If dropping it in means that you want it to go after the article you've dropped it below: take that article's page number, set the new article's page number to be `above article page number + above article length` and then update all articles with a higher page number to have `page number = page number + new article length`